# How can I test a CRON job with PHP?

Tags: php, cron, kohana, kohana-3

This is the first time I've ever used a CRON.

I'm using it to parse external data that is automatically FTP'd to a subdirectory on our site.

I have created a controller and model which handles the data. I can access the URL fine in my browser and it works (however I will be restricting this soon).

My problem is, how can I test if it's working?

I've added this to my controller for a quick and dirty log

```
$file = 'test.txt';

        $contents = '';

        if (file_exists($file)) {

            $contents = file_get_contents($file);

        }

        $contents .= date('m-d-Y') . ' --- ' . PHP_SAPI . "\n\n";

        file_put_contents($file, $contents);
```

But so far only got requests logged from myself from the browser, despite having my CRON running ever minute.

```
03-18-2010 --- cgi-fcgi

03-18-2010 --- cgi-fcgi
```

I've set it up using cPanel with the command

`index.php properties/update/`

the 2nd portion is what I use to access the page in my browser.

So how can I test this is working properly, and have I stuffed anything up?

Note: I'm using Kohana 3.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the correct command for calling Kohana.

Make sure you're using the full path to index.php so you can eliminate any path errors. Here are the [switches available for use in Kohana](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/request.php#L110):

- --**uri**: Self explanatory
- --**method**: HTTP Request method (POST, GET, etc ...) (Overrides Kohana::$method)
- --**get**: Formatted GET data
- --**post**: Formatted POST data

You should be using something like this:

```
php /path/to/kohana/directory/index.php --uri=properties/update/
```

I can't remember if you need double quotes around the value, don't forget to try that if it doesn't work.

Comment: One thing I may suggest to your answer, is to not place the word `application` in your example path. It threw me, because there actually is a folder named application in Kohana which does not have an `index.php`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't think of that at the time -_-' Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

you probably aren't running Cron with root permissions on that file.

put `mailto="youremail@yourdomain.tld"` at the start of the cron file to have it email you errors.

If you don't have root access to the cron file (I.E. SSH) I don't know if you can do this in cPanel.