# Kohana 3 and CRON always accessing index.php (not following the URI argument)

Tags: php, cron, kohana, kohana-3, cpanel

OK, I hope this is my last question about CRON jobs and Kohana 3. Note: others are not duplicates, just other problems.

Here is my CRON job (setup in cPanel)

```
php /home/user/public_html/index.php --uri=properties/update
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468037/how-can-i-test-a-cron-job-with-php/2470647#2470647).

I have set it up so it emails me the output. It is running every 5 mins.

Unfortunately, it always emails me the source of the home page of my site (index.php or /).

I can access that URL fine in my browser, i.e. `http://www.example.com/properties/update` and it works and does its job correctly. I can tell the Cron is never hitting the script because I have a [file logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468037/how-can-i-test-a-cron-job-with-php) in place.

Would this have anything to do with .htaccess?

Has this happened to anyone before, and how did they fix it?

Many thanks.

### Update

Here is my home route in `bootstrap.php` if anyone is interested.

```
Route::set('home', '')
    ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action' => 'index'
    ));
```

It is the first route defined.

### Another Update

What's weird too, is that a `var_dump(Kohana::$is_cli);` produces `false` when emailed from the CRON.

Comment: It does not have anything to do with .htaccess - that's a file for Apache and won't affect anything since you're running PHP directly.

Comment: @jimyi Thought so. Still learning about Crons so though I'd clear that up.

Comment: If you want to run the scripts in "exactly the same way" as a browser would, using wget is a good alternative. If it's available on your server.

I guess you would run into some issues if you have suppressed the index.php (in htaccess + bootstrap.php) and try to just execute the index.php using php from the command line. For instance you're URL::site() would not work any longer.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else has this problem, after spending hours trying to work it out, I eventually discovered that instead of using (to use your example)

```
php /home/user/public_html/index.php --uri=properties/update
```

I had to use

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/user/public_html/index.php --uri=properties/update
```

The exact path to **php** may vary, but without using this, it wasn't using CLI, and although I'm not entirely sure, I *think* it was CURLing it.

I also found that I had to explicitly state the index actions too, when calling those; they weren't called as the controllers' default actions (although oddly, before() *was* called).

Answer (score 0):

Update your route to:

```
Route::set('home', '<>')
    ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action' => 'index'
    ));
```

or:

```
Route::set('home', 'properties/update')
    ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action' => 'index'
    ));
```